# catch computername from error

Tags: powershell

How to catch the computername from the error variable in below code?

```
$FilterHashTable = @{
    logname='Application';
    providername='Microsoft-Windows-SoftwareRestrictionPolicies';
    StartTime=$StartTime
};
$test = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
            param ($FilterHashTable)
            Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashTable
        } -ArgumentList $FilterHashTable -ComputerName $cpu -ErrorVariable blad1 |
        Select-Object PSComputerName, TimeCreated, Message |
        Export-Csv $logFile -Encoding UTF8

if ($blad1) {
    foreach ($blad1 in $test) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where does error come from? All we need to know is the contents of the error variable

Comment: Hmm i dont understend. I like to catch cpuname from 2 errors
1. When question cant connect to remote cpu.
2. When none events found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the target computer is stored in the `TargetObject` property of the error variable.

```
if ($blad1) {
    $blad1 | ForEach-Object {
        'Error getting events from computer {0}.' -f $_.TargetObject
    }
}
```

To get more information about the value of a variable use [`Get-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) (to list the properties and methods of objects) and [`Format-List`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx) (to display the values of all object properties in list form).

```
$blad1 | Get-Member
$blad1 | Format-List * -Force
```

Comment: Its work only for error with cant connect to remote cpu.
I dont know how do this for another error with (not events were found)

Comment: @cinq2 Those errors should have an `OriginInfo` property.